# 2-column dropdownlist with one column hidden

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

I'm hoping this is a quick one.  Sorry, still an ASP/C# n00b and I can't seem to find an example.

What I want to do is have a dropdownlist on an ASP page.  I want the list to display 2 values; Benefit Type and Priority.  However, the dropdownlist is used as a filter for the data to display, so my field names in the table are BENTYP and PRIO.  So, the user will see "Benefit Type", but the code-behind will be able to read "BENTYP".  It's sort of like a 2-column combo box with one column hidden.

Make sense?  I know this is a snap in Access, I can't imagine it's too hard in ASP but I just don't have the experience yet.  Also, if you would be so kind, can you tell me how the code-behind would read the text in the "hidden" column?

EDIT: Just to be clear, the dropdownlist would look something like this:

Column1 (visible)     Column2 (invisible)

Benefit Type  ---- BENTYP

Priority -----------  PRIO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
           <asp:DropDownList id="List"
                AutoPostBack="True"
                OnSelectedIndexChanged="Selection_Change"
                runat="server">

              <asp:ListItem Value="BENTYP"> Benefit Type </asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem Value="PRIO"> Priority </asp:ListItem>

           </asp:DropDownList>
```

From code behind you just have to access the thing you want:

```
       string item1 = List.DataTextField.ToString();
       string item2 = List.DataValueField.ToString();
```

Hope it helps.

[Founded in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

What you've asked is exactly the functionality of the dropdown, it has a "Value" and a "Text" for each item it contains, just set the value as your second column and your text as the first.

From the code behind you can add it like so:

```
ListItem item = new ListItem("text (first column)", "value (second column)");
item.Selected = true; // whatever you want here
yourDropdownList.Items.Add(item);
```

To get the selected item in the code behind (the ListItem object) use:

```
var item = yourDropdownList.SelectedItem;
var text = item.Text;
var val = item.Value;
```